# How to solve $79 n + 1 = 2^a 3^b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How could you solve something like:

> Find the smallest $n \in \mathbb N^+$ such that $79 n + 1 = 2^a 3^b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb N$

by non-brute force methods?

Comment: There may be a nice way to get the smallest. Certainly $a=78$, $b=0$ works!

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think there is! $2^{-1}3^4\equiv 1\pmod {79}$, so you can decrease $a$ by one and increase $b$ by $4$ freely, working both $\pmod{78}$. Even more, my code shows those are the only family of solutions starting from $a=0,b=78$ (without counting $a=b=0$).

Comment: $a=19,b=2$ gives fairly small $n$

Comment: @WillJagy yes, that is the smallest

Comment: In what context was this given to you?

Comment: In thinking about another problem I realised that it implied $An+1 = 2^a 3^b$ should always have a solution. I started investigating how high $a$ and $b$ would have to go to find them.

Comment: It doesn't always has a solution in positive integers, think about $A=6$ .

Comment: Ah, yes I was only thinking about numbers relatively prime to 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $3^4\equiv 2\pmod {79}$, it is necessary that:

$$3^{4a+b}\equiv1\pmod{79}$$
Since $3$ is a primitive root $\pmod{79}$, we want $4a+b=78$ minimizing $k=a\log2+b\log3$. $a=19,b=2$ is the most obvious solution, where $a$ is maximal. Now,  since decreasing $a$ by one forces us to increase $b$ by $4$, and $\log2<4\log3$, we see that it is in fact the most optimal solution.

Comment: Replacing $79$ with $101$ the smallest solution is $101 * 126283 + 1= 2^3 3^{13}$

If we can invert your method then there's a $n$ such that $100-3*n =13$ or $100-13*n = 3$

We find $100-3*29=13$ which suggests $3^{29} \equiv 2 \pmod{101}$, and it is.

Comment: I am not sure we can reverse the method, because we used that $\log2<4\log3$. Maybe if one base is much greater than the other this could make a counterexample.  I will see if I can get some properties on the converse.

Comment: Not always, no. $41 * 7 + 1 = 2^5 3^2$ but there's no $n$ such that $40-2n=5$ or $40-5n = 2$

Comment: And $39 * 105 + 1 = 2^{12} 3^0$ is another kettle of fish.

Comment: @Neil That happens because neither $\log_2{3}$ or $\log_3{2}$ exists $\pmod{41}$ ($\log$ being the discrete logarithm), which gives a nice counterexample. Now the question is: When is the converse true?